# Troubleshooting 500 Error Due to Cookie Size

Tags: varnish

Visitors to a website get 500 Internal Server error after browsing for a bit due to a tracking cookie that pushes the overall cookie size for our domain to over 4kb (it's a page view cookie so it appends the page name each time you visit a new page).

I can reproduce the issue using curl with a very large cookie payload. In doing this I've been able to verify where exactly the 500 is coming from (we go from Cloudflare to Varnish to the backend webserver). I've verified that the requests that fail don't make it to the webserver, so I believe Varnish is the one serving up the 500s. I have also watched the varnishlog and seen the 500s come through.

This is an example response from the varnishlog

```
--  VCL_return     hash
--  VCL_call       HASH
--  VCL_return     lookup
--  Hit            57254162
--  VCL_call       HIT
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
--  RespStatus     200
--  RespReason     OK
--  RespHeader     X-Powered-By: Express
--  RespHeader     Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 23:05:52 GMT
--  RespHeader     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
--  RespHeader     Content-Length: 1174
--  RespHeader     X-Varnish: 57156196 57519178
--  RespHeader     Age: 86
--  RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
--  VCL_call       DELIVER
--  RespHeader     X-Cache: HIT
--  RespUnset      X-Powered-By: Express
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Timestamp      Process: 1564700838.564547 0.000354 0.000354
--  RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
--  Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
--  RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
--  Error          workspace_client overflow
--  RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
--  RespStatus     500
--  RespReason     Internal Server Error
--  Timestamp      Resp: 1564700838.564580 0.000387 0.000033
--  ReqAcct        10063 0 10063 0 0 0
--  End
```

Here is what I'd added to the vcl_recv section to remove the offending cookie

```
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_loc_[^;]+(; )?", "");
```

I don't understand what the significance is of two RespStatus entries here. Why is it 200, and then 500? I've also noticed that if I use curl, which is using HTTP/1.1 I get the 500, but if I use HTTPie, which uses HTTP/2, I get a 200. Is that expected? Would Varnish handle the cookie size differently depending on the http version?

*Edited: I think I've figured out that the difference in the two response statuses are that one is the delivery of the content to varnish, and the second is the delivery of the content to the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the log says, the workspace is too small to accommodate the transaction (headers, notably), try increasing it:

```
varnishadm param.set workspace_client 128k
```

For a long explanation: varnish uses a "worspace" for each transaction. This is a chunk of memory used to allocate data, and the whole chunk is wiped out at the end of the transaction. The headers notably are copied into the workspace, and everytime to add or modify a header, it goes there too.

Ths issue here is that you don't have enough space. Earlier version would just panic, but it's now smarter and just produces a synthetic response with a 500 status. The trick is that it realizes the lack of workspace after the initial response has been copied, so you see both responses in the log.